# Extjs grid sorting

Tags: sorting, extjs, grid

I have a column- `Company` in **ExtJs gridPanel**.

In the backend I have put a condition -

```
{id:'Company',header: "Company",  sortable: true, dataIndex: 'comp', 
     renderer: function(value, cell) {
   if(status='unemployed') 
      {  return 'n/a';}
}
```

Now,If the column has values like `'Apple'` ,`'Google'`,`'n/a'`,`'Microsoft'`, It is not sorting it in proper order. How should I handle `'n/a'` while sorting?

Comment: Sorting does it before render, so you should handle 'unemployed'. This just a side note.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use just blank value for the n/a case. It would appear on the top of the list.
You can also to put a space before 'n', like `' n/a'`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but it didnt work. The problem here is -if(status='unemployed') 
      {  return 'n/a';}
}. Here 'status' is the value of another column in the grid. I guess this is causing problem because even if I change 'n/a' to 'abcd', I face the same issue.

Comment: The problem is in comparation: you should use `==` instead of `=`.